# How to convert UTF8 to LITHUANIAN_CI_AS in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

we have MySQL in UTF8_unicode_ci and when we export text to MSSQL database which is  LITHUANIAN_CI_AS text is not displayed correctly. How to convert text in UTF8_unicode_ci to text in LITHUANIAN_CI_AS in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to convert text from [...]_ci anywhere as this attribute refers to the collation used and not to a feature of the text itself.

collation means "how text is sorted".